# Why is my 'data' param in a Vue.js Storybook not overriding the data of the component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, storybook

I have the following component, meant to minimally reproduce this issue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    foo is: {{foo}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'demo',
  data: function() {
    return {
      foo: 'bar',
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

With a corresponding story:

```
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/vue';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';

import Demo from '../src/components/Demo';

storiesOf('Demo', module)
  .add('default', () => {
    return {
      components: {Demo},
      template: '<div style="width: 500px"><Demo/></div>',
    }
  })
  .add('foo is baz', () => {
    return {
      components: {Demo},
      template: '<div style="width: 500px"><Demo/></div>',
      data: () => ({
        foo: 'baz',
      }),
    }
  });
```

As you can see from this screenshot, the value of "foo" in the component doesn't update to "baz", even though I have specified `data` as a function in the return value from the story. What is going wrong?

[image: Picture of storybook where the story 'foo is baz' is highlighted, but the text reads 'foo is bar']

Comment: I _think_ `foo` would need to be a `prop` for this to work. Look at how `tasks` is defined in [this component](https://www.learnstorybook.com/intro-to-storybook/vue/en/composite-component/), and then how they pass that data in [that story](https://www.learnstorybook.com/intro-to-storybook/vue/en/data/) (scroll until you see an image, and look at the code right above it).

Comment: I removed `data` and added `props: {foo: 'baz'}` but it's still not working.

Comment: Did you do exactly as in the example they give? eg. in your component add `props: { foo: {type: String, default: 'bar'}}` and remove `data` and then in your story, keep `data: () =>...` exactly like you posted